# Batch txt to excel delimited using vba question

Tags: excel

I was trying to batch convert text files to excel using VBA and found this code in this web. This is how my text looks like:

ABC|123|DEF

ZZZ|233|YTU

```
Sub LoopAllFiles()
    Dim sPath As String, sDir As String
    sPath = "C:\work\"
    If Right(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"
    sDir = Dir$(sPath & "*.txt", vbNormal)
    Do Until Len(sDir) = 0
        Workbooks.Open (sPath & sDir)
        With ActiveWorkbook
            Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
                :="|", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            .SaveAs Filename:=Left(.FullName, InStrRev(.FullName, ".")) & "xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
            .Close
        End With
        sDir = Dir$
    Loop
End Sub
```

After using the code, the exported excel looks like this:

ABC 123 DEF (3 separated cell)

ZZZ|233|YTU (1 single cell)

Anyone have idea why the code only convert the first row and stop afterwards?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Instead of `Selection.TextToColumns...` try `Cells.TextToColumns`, or even better would be to provide a specific range.

Comment: That does not work for me. A runtime error 1004 appeared saying that Microsoft excel can convert only one column at a time

Comment: D'oh, then do `Range("A1:A100").TextToColumns` (or whatever range you need).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, TextToColumns will work on the selected text, which by default is a single cell, but you need it to be the range of cells of the imported data. Try expanding the selection before doing the TextToColumns, for example, insert the following code line: 
    `Selection.CurrentRegion.Select` 
after 
    `With ActiveWorkbook`